# Font in siunitx S-column

Tags: tables, siunitx, s-column-type

I am having some trouble with the siunitx package and its S column. I am trying to create a regression table where the regression coefficients and the t-statistics are aligned on the decimal using the S column from siunitx. The problem I am encountering is the fact that the numbers in the table seem to have the math font, whereas I would prefer to have the same font as the rest of the text (Times). The result is the following:
[image]

I've tried several different solutions, including the use of the detect-all, detect-weight, and detect-family options but none seem to work for me. A minimum working example is provided below. Hope someone can help me, all help is appreciated!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{times}
\sisetup{detect-all=true}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
\centering
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()}, parse-numbers=false}
\caption{Regression\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{lSSSSSS}
\toprule
                    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Alpha Post}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}\\
\midrule
Variable 1  & -0.0115  &          &                 & -0.0107   & -0.0302*      & -0.0121         \\
                           & (-1.38)  &          &                 & (-0.97)   & (-1.75)             & (-0.21)         \\
\addlinespace
Variable 2 &          & -0.00101 &                 & -0.000283 & -0.000841           & -0.000408         \\
                           &          & (-1.57)  &                 & (-0.35)   & (-0.95)             & (-0.19)         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t}-statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize * \(p<.10\), ** \(p<.05\), *** \(p<.01\)}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Using the advice from Mico I changed my `times` and `amsmath` packages to `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` respectively and it seems to have solved the issue.
[image: Solution]

Comment: Note that the `times` package is a deprecated text-only font package. I suggest you load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the comment, was unaware of the fact that the `times` package was deprecated. Changing my `times` and `amsmath` packages to `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` respectively seems to have solved the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: I sugest to use the package `mathptmx` if you want a roman-like font option that supports math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to loading a suitable Times Roman math font, you should provide the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive to make sure that the columns fully span the width of the `tabular*` environment. Providing a bit more structure to the header would also be helpful.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,rotating}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out inter-col. whitespace
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()}, parse-numbers=false}
\caption{Regression\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{6}{S[table-format=-2.6]} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Alpha Post}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
&{(1)}&{(2)}&{(3)}&{(4)}&{(5)}&{(6)}\\
\midrule
Variable 1 & -0.0115 & & & -0.0107 & -0.0302* & -0.0121 \\
           & (-1.38) & & & (-0.97) & (-1.75) & (-0.21) \\
\addlinespace
Variable 2 & & -0.00101 & & -0.000283 & -0.000841 & -0.000408 \\
           & & (-1.57) & & (-0.35) & (-0.95) & (-0.19) \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t}-statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize * \(p<.10\), ** \(p<.05\), *** \(p<.01\)}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```